# How to get the real value of a user-defined type data?

Tags: ocaml

If I define:

```
type value =
    | Value of int
    | Error of string;;
```

and if I want to use the real int value of some Value as part of the computation, like:

```
let v1 = Value 3;;
let v2 = Value 4;;
```

If I write:

```
let sum = v1 + v2;;
```

Then I would get an error message

> Error: This expression has type value but an expression was expected of type                                     │
>            int

So if I want to calculate the sum of `v1` and `v2`. How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your `value` type is different from `int` in that the former has either of the `Value` and `Error` tags.  You need to write code that deals with both cases, for example like:

```
# match v1 with Error e1 -> Error e1 | Value i1 ->
#   (match v2 with Error e2 -> Error e2 | Value i2 ->
#      Value (i1 + i2)) ;;
- : value = Value 7
```

Or you can write a function:

```
# let sum x1 x2 =
#   (match x1 with Error e1 -> Error e1 | Value i1 ->
#      (match x2 with Error e2 -> Error e2 | Value i2 ->
#         Value (i1 + i2))) ;;
val sum : value -> value -> value = <fun>
# sum v1 v2 ;;
- : value = Value 7
```

You can also use the standard `'a option` type (with `Some` and `None` tags instead of your `Value` and `Error`) for a similar purpose (although it is polymorphic/generic with respect to the contents type `'a` and does not contain a `string` in the error case):

```
# let v1 = Some 3 ;;
val v1 : int option = Some 3
# let v2 = Some 4 ;;
val v2 : int option = Some 4
# let sum x1 x2 =
#   (match x1 with None -> None | Some i1 ->
#      (match x2 with None -> None | Some i2 ->
#         Some (i1 + i2))) ;;
val sum : int option -> int option -> int option = <fun>
# sum v1 v2 ;;
- : int option = Some 7
```

Or better:

```
# let sum x1 x2 =
#   match (x1, x2) with
#   | (Some i1, Some i2) -> Some (i1 + i2)
#   | _ -> None ;;
val sum : int option -> int option -> int option = <fun>
# sum v1 v2 ;;
- : int option = Some 7
```

As an advanced topic, you may also google for the "option monad" (also known as the "maybe monad") for simpler notation.

You may also use exceptions instead of `option` as a less functional alternative.